# Quickly compute millions of values for a search

Tags: sql, math

Let's say I have a database of millions of widgets with a price attribute. Widgets belong to suppliers, and I sell widgets to customers by first buying them from suppliers and then selling them to the customer. With this basic setup, if a customer asks me for every widget less than $50, it's trivial to list them.

However, I mark up the price of widgets from individual suppliers differently. So I may mark up widgets from Supplier A by 10%, and I may mark up widgets from Supplier B by a flat rate of $5. In a database, these markups would be stored in a join table with my ID, the supplier ID, a markup type (flat, percentage), and a markup rate. On top of this, suppliers may add their own markups when they sell to me (these markups would be in the same join table with the supplier's ID, my ID, and a markup type/rate).

So if I want to sell a $45 widget from Supplier A, it might get marked up by the supplier's 10% markup (to $49.50), and then my own $10 flat markup (to $59.50). This widget would not show up in the client's search for widgets costing less than $50. However, it's possible that an $80 widget could get marked down to $45 by the time it reaches the client, and should be returned in results. These markups are subject to change, and let's assume I'm one of hundreds of people in this system selling widgets to customers through suppliers, all with their own markup relationships in that markup table.

Is there any precedent for performing calculations like this quickly across millions of objects? I realize this is a huge, non-trivial problem, but I'm curious how one would start addressing a problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any precedent for performing calculations like this quickly across millions of 
>   objects?

Standard. Seriously. Data warehouse, risk projections. Stuff like that - your problem is small. Precaulcuate all combinations, store them in a proper higher level database server, finished.

it is not huge - seriously. It is only huge for a small server, but once you get a calculation grid going... it is quite trivial. Millions of objects? Calculate 100.000 objects in a minute per machine, 10 million are 100 minute objects. And you dont have THAT many changes.

Comment: This is certainly an option I've thought about. The structure of these orders is subject to change, so in the future it's possible that Client A may purchase from Seller X, who purchases from Seller Y, who purchases finally from Supplier K, with markups happening multiple times throughout.

Comment: Irrelevant. Seriously. Proper hardware and technology will handle hundreds of millions of rows without problems. This is a minor issue similar to any risk management data warehouse - try doing that with a million transactions per day that you evaluate in a thousand combinations each, multiple times per day - THEN you talk about volume.

Answer (score 5):

Add columns to your database and store the computed results, updating them with the related records change. You cannot calculate these values on the fly for *millions* of records.

Comment: The markup rules are subject to change, and will yield different results for different people performing the search. Customer A may see a 15% markup + a $10 markup on Widget A, while Customer B may see just a $12 markup on the same widget, depending on who they're purchasing through.

Comment: Then you're going to have to create *more* columns. The point is that you have to "cache" the computed values. There is simply no way to search/sort against a computed field involving multiple joins for *millions* of records.

Comment: The issue is, even if we did that, every time a markup rule changed, a customer was added, or a widget price changed, we'd have to perform millions of computations, anyway. Granted this is less of a problem than something that happens as the result of a request.

Comment: Those calculations can be done asynchronously in a background process. Those same calculations cannot be performed in real-time in response to a customer's search.